# ggplot GLMM binary outcome

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models

I'm looking for a way to plot a GLMM that has a binary outcome variable where they either responded correctly or incorrectly (response) and 1 factor with 8 levels (level) that was each repeated 24 times for 20 people (id).

I'd like to produce a plot where the probability of responding correctly to the level is on the y-axis and each person is plotted as a different coloured dot on the x-axis containing the levels. This is sort of getting me in the ballpark but it's not really what I want and I'm pretty sure it isn't the proper way to do it. With 20 people the colour becomes a gradient and it's impossible to tell who is where. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = level, y = response, group = id, colour = id)) +
       geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "glm", family= "binomial", se = FALSE)
```

Here is a small reproducible example with 3 people and 2 levels.

```
df <- data.frame("id"=c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(3,10)), 
      "level"=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
      "response"=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1))
       df$level <- factor(df$level)
       df$id <- factor(df$id)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about the purpose? Do you really need to recognize particular id values?  With a large number of individuals it will always be hard to distinguish them by colour. Some possibilities I can think of: (1) give up on distinguishing individuals and just use an uncoloured 'spaghetti plot' to visualize the degree of heterogeneity; (2) subdivide individuals into smaller groups (arbitrarily or according to some id-level characteristic) and separate into facets; (3) use dynamic graphics to mouse over/highlight individuals.

Comment: Hi Ben. The main purpose is to visually illustrate that the results of the model might be slightly misleading as half the group has a high probability of making more more errors, while the other half do not, causing them to cancel out somewhat and diminishing the effect. The graph will have to be static unfortunately as it's going into a dissertation.